# Shinken probe on windows server but windows server on VPN network (monitoring server outside VPN)

Tags: windows, vpn, monitoring, nagios, shinken

I need to monitore a windows server with skinken, but this server is accessible with a VPN connection (with strong security, done by an electronic tool and human action).

The monitoring server is not connected to this VPN so I search a solution to receive monitoring from the Windows server without VPN connection.

Is it possible for the windows server to send result of probe directly to Shinken ?
I wan to monitor this kind of informations:

- hardware data (cpu, ram, space free, etc.)
- status of apache server and some other services

Best regards,
Philippe

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for the windows server to send result of probe directly to Shinken ?

If you mean that your Windows server can connect to the monitoring server without VPN, but not the other way around, then it might be possible. Depending on Shinken (which I have never used), there may be a way so send in passive check results via, for example, an HTTP API.

Looking at [this documentation](https://shinken.readthedocs.io/en/latest/05_thebasics/passivechecks.html#submitting-passive-host-check-results) however, it doesn't mention anything about passive checks over API.

You may want to have a look at [this article](https://shinken.readthedocs.io/en/latest/06_medium/passive-checks.html#passive-data-acquisition) instead, I don't really understand it since I don't know what Shinken terms like "Arbiter" or "Receiver" is, but yes, Nagios can accept passive results as long as you have a way to submit them.